# How to make a QlikView dashboard with variances?

Tags: dashboard, qlikview

How can I make a dashboard in QlikView, showing variances for some results?

The final screen should:

- Show the results.
- Show up-or-down arrow for every result.

I'm pretty sure it is possible, as Google image search (for a keyword 'qlikview') shows such dashboard (I highlighted those arrows with a black rectangle):

[image]

Comment: You are correct, this is pretty easy to do in Qlik, see [here](https://community.qlik.com/thread/102755). If you are using Qlik personal edition and cannot open external .qvw's, there is some useful info buried in the posts that should get you up and running. You'll likely need to use some set expressions in your `if` condition, so see [this](https://community.qlik.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/245786-42707/QlikLearn-Set-Analysis.pdf) for a crash course in set analysis.

Comment: Also, rather than use 'variances', the right terminology in Qlik is 'visual cues'. Searching on that will give you much better results. Cheers.

Comment: Visual queues are only for the text and background colour. A better way and the way to get the arrows is to use the image representation option of an expression. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those arrows you need to create an expression that tells you if the variance is positive or negative.

```
if(column(1)-column(2)>0,'Positive',
if(column(1)-column(2)<0,'Negative',
'Same'))
```

Now all we need to do is change the words Positive etc. to arrows. This is done in the expression editor.

[image: Images Tab]

Then you can just select one of the built in arrows which will paste some odd looking text but all it's saying is that instead of the word 'Positive' use the picture that is at 'qmem:///buitin/arrow_n_g.png'.

Giving a result like this.

[image]